# Crashlytics don't compile when using Jack

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-jack-and-jill

I tried to use new experimental tool chain for Android ([Jack and Jill](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill)), but if fails to compile with:

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsXXX'.
> Task with path 'dexXXX' not found in project ':app'.
```

I'm pretty sure it's due to J&J being in early development stage, but can anyone explain what happens here and maybe provide a workaround?

Comment: Deobs means it's like a flavor that is not obfuscated? We might need to see more of your build.gradle setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crashlytics task depends on `dex` task, which will not be created, because Jack does dexing internally. This is most likely something Crashlytics team will have to deal with soon and fix.

Comment: https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlyticsstoredeobs-task-fails-with-enabled-shrinker/60935

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here.

We released support for this in 1.22.0 of our Gradle plugin with improved Jack support.